# Алгоритм Сложности java TreeSet

Tags: java, алгоритм, treeset

Какого сложность вставки в TreeSet который имеет заданный нами comparator??

Comment: `O(log N)` вызовов компаратора. А там уже смотря что написали.

Comment: Какого что?? :)

Comment: Более детально опишу,есть класс продукт который имеет 5 свойств ,в том числе цена,компаратор сортирует по цене,алгоритм вставки в такой TreeSet равно O(log (n)) ???

Comment: [This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)